# Pulling second column only from XML into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, xml

I'm trying to pull in an external file which contains only 2 columns but several rows, the first is just a numeric reference in ascending order and should be just skipped but the second contains value which I need to push into an array so they can be injected into the page. So far all I can get it to do is pull in all the values.

```
var catalogIn = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'content-catalog.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (returnedXMLResponse) {
        $(returnedXMLResponse).find('Row').each(function () {
            // loop over each cell
            $('Data', this).each(function () {
                // push row into main array
                catalogIn.push($(this).text());
            });
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not check against column index then decide if you should add the element to array or not

```
var catalogIn = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'content-catalog.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (returnedXMLResponse) {
        $(returnedXMLResponse).find('Row').each(function () {
            // loop over each cell
            $('Data', this).each(function (index) {
                if(index == 1) {
                // push row into main array
                catalogIn.push($(this).text());
                }
            });
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to parse the xml response like

```
var xmlresponse = $.parseXML(returnedXMLResponse);
```

Then find a node by looping the `xmlresponse`.

```
var $xml = $(xmlresponse);
var $data = $xml.find("<your node>");

$data.each(function(){

    var column1= $(this).find('your column 1').text(),
     var column2= $(this).find('your column 2').text(); 
});
```